# Print the most repeated word in a string

Tags: java, string

Write a java program to find the most repeated word in a string and also print its frequency.

---

### INPUT

are you are

### OUTPUT

are: 2

---

This question can be done by using HashMap or file reader (I suppose) but actually, I haven't learned them yet.

Yet, I managed to write a code that displays the frequency (but not the word)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class duplicatewords
   {
       void main()
       {
           Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter the string");
           String str=sc.nextLine();
           String arr[]=str.split(" ");
           int count=1; int checkvalue=0;
           for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
           {
               String temp=arr[i];
               for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
               {
                   String anothertemp=arr[j];
                   if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(anothertemp))
                   count++;
                }
                if(checkvalue<c)
                checkvalue=c;
                c=1;
            }
            System.out.println(checkvalue);
        }
    }
```

I want to know how to print the word also without using any map or reader.

I think the program will be a very complicated one but I will understand.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need some form of map to map each word to its count. If you do not want to use the existing `Map` implementations of Java, you can start by implementing your own map structure using only arrays, but I think this will be a futile effort.

Comment: yeah, ikr. So should I assume this question cannot be done without using any map?

Comment: Will, counting the number of unique words work and, maybe, then something can be done?

Comment: You need an associative data structure that allows a counter per word, so that it can hold {are: 2, you: 1}. Since the key of that structure is `String`, you cannot use an array without converting the key to `int`, at which point you've arrived at what a `HashMap` does.

Comment: @Zootopia It can be done without a `Map`. That is just probably the easiest way to do it. If this is a school assignment, you should do it using the means that they have taught you to this point.

Comment: this is not a school assignment ....it was asked in an interview

Comment: @Zootopia then use a map! :D

Comment: You can use 2 arrays: one holds the words, one holds the count. The connection is made using the same index value.

Comment: @Zootopia you may want to check this answer I provided for a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67026362/calculate-keyword-density-of-each-unique-element-in-list-in-java/67051607#67051607. Let me know what you think. For your problem, however, all you need is a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the word and the value is the count. Keep in mind that you need to get the value of a given key and if it exists, increment the value by one. If not, put the key value pair with the value set to 1.

Comment: Or an array which holds an `Object{word,count}` and then always iterate the array to find the object to update. This works, but it is very inefficient

Comment: An array solution, while functional, is very slow for retrieval.

Comment: @Zootopia I think you need to consider the edge case when more than one word have the same frequency. For example, what if two or three words are the most frequent words? Do you want to return _any_ of these words or do you want to return _all_ words? If you need to know _all_ words, you need to consider the solution I posted.

Comment: @knittl what do you think about my inverted map solution?

Comment: @hfontanez thanks

Comment: @Zootopia You're welcome. I wanted you to consider other use cases. That's why I provided you with the link of my other post where I created a custom data structure to capture this data. Then, on my answer here provided two solutions, with one a bit better than the other. Sometimes, solution one is good enough and sometimes it is not. I still believe solution two is better for the aforementioned reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, to get the most frequent word, existing code needs to be modified slightly just to provide a variable for the most repeated variable which has to be updated when a more frequent word is detected.  No extra arrays/data structures is needed for this specific task.

```java
String arr[] = str.split(" ");
int maxFreq = 0;
String mostRepeated = null;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String temp = arr[i];
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[j]))
            count++;
    }
    if (maxFreq < count) {
       maxFreq = count;
       mostRepeated = temp;
    }
}
System.out.println(mostRepeated + ": " + maxFreq);
```

For the input:

```java
String str = "I am he as you are he as you are me and we are all together";
```

Output:

```
are: 3
```

---

A bit faster implementation could include setting the duplicated values to `null` to skip them later:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (null == arr[i]) continue;
    String temp = arr[i];
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[j])) {
            count++;
            arr[j] = null;
        }
    }
    if (maxFreq < count) {
       maxFreq = count;
       mostRepeated = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution using 2 arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "are you are";
    String[] words = input.split(" ");

    //the 10 is the limit of individual words:
    String[] wordsBucket = new String[10];
    Integer[] countBucket = new Integer[10];

    for(String word:words){
        int index = findIndex(word, wordsBucket);
        incrementIndex(countBucket, index);
    }
    int highest = findMax(countBucket);

    System.out.println(wordsBucket[highest]+": "+countBucket[highest]);
}

private static int findMax(Integer[] countBucket) {
    int max = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<countBucket.length;i++) {
        if(countBucket[i]==null) {
            break;
        }
        if(countBucket[i] > max) {
            max = countBucket[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

private static int findIndex(String word, String[] wordsBucket) {
    for(int i=0;i<wordsBucket.length;i++) {
        if(word.equals(wordsBucket[i])) {
            return i;
        }
        if(wordsBucket[i] == null) {
            wordsBucket[i] = word;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private static void incrementIndex(Integer[] countBucket, int index) {
    if(countBucket[index] == null){
        countBucket[index] = 1;
    } else {
        countBucket[index]++;
    }
}
```

This prints `are: 2`. As @knittl pointed out in the comments this can also be done with 1 array of `Pair<String, Integer>` or something similar.

If you are allowed to use `Map`s and streams, then this works too (using the same `String[] words` as input as above):

```
Map<String, Integer> countingMap = new HashMap<>();
Arrays.stream(words).forEach(w->countingMap.compute(w, (ww,c)->c==null?1:c+1));
Map.Entry<String, Integer> h = countingMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue).reversed()).findFirst().get();
System.out.println(h);
```

This prints `are=2`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. It just maintains a list of words to count and adjust the max while iterating thru the list.

- scratch arrays are allocated to the max number of words.
- `cnt` is adjust to control iterating thru updated arrays based on discovered words.

```
String s =
        "this when this how to now this why apple when when other now this now";
String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
int cnt = 0;
int idx = -1;
String[] list = new String[words.length];
int[] count = new int[words.length];
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cnt; k++) {
        if (list[k].equals(words[i])) {
            count[k]++;
            if (count[k] > max) {
                max = count[k];
                idx = k;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    count[cnt] = 1;
    list[cnt++] = words[i];
}

System.out.println(words[idx] + " " + max);
```

prints

```
this 4
```

And here is yet another solution using streams.  This simply creates a map of word counts then finds the first entry that has the greatest count.  Ties are ignored.

```
Entry<String, Integer> result = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r, q -> 1,
                (a, b) -> a + 1))
        .entrySet().stream().max(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .get();

System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
this=4
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions, but one is better than the other.

### Solution one: use `Map<String, Integer>`

```
public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrase = "This example is very good but is not very efficient";
        String[] words = phrase.split(" ");
        List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
        
        Map<String, Integer> wordCountMap = wordList.parallelStream().
                collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
                        w -> w, w -> 1, Integer::sum));
            
        System.out.println(wordCountMap);
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
{but=1, very=2, not=1, efficient=1, This=1, is=2, good=1, example=1}
```

As you can see, `very` and `is` are tied for the most frequent word. This is why this solution is not the most efficient. What if you could reverse the map in order to group words with similar frequency together?

### Solution two: use `Map<Integer, List<String>>`

In my opinion, this is a better solution. This solution will group all words with similar count. Using the same input of the solution above, words with similar frequency will be bundled together. So, when querying the map for the highest count, both `very` and `is` will be returned as expected. Using Lambda expressions makes this task of "inverting" the map very easy:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapInverted = 
        wordCountMap.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
        
System.out.println(mapInverted);
```

After adding these lines to the sample code from solution one, I now have an aggregation of words of similar word counts:

```
{1=[but, not, efficient, This, good, example], 2=[very, is]}
```

For both of these approaches, the way to get the max value:

```
Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = Collections.max(wordCountMap.entrySet(),
                (Entry<String, Integer> e1, Entry<String, Integer> e2) -> e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue())); // for solution one
System.out.println(maxEntry); // outputs: very=2

Entry<Integer, List<String>> maxKey = Collections.max(mapInverted.entrySet(),
                (Entry<Integer, List<String>> e1, Entry<Integer, List<String>> e2) -> e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey())); // for solution two
System.out.println(maxKey); // outputs: 2=[very, is]
```