# Removing words from a text file in java

Tags: java, stop-words

I am having some problems with this Java task.

I have two files — ***hello.txt*** and ***stopwords.txt***. I am just trying to remove the words that are in the *stopwords.txt* file in the *hello.txt* file and have the frequency of the top *n* elements in the updated hello file displayed in the console.

I know how to do this in python, but not in java. I believe a hash map would be the best approach for this.

Thank you very much!

I have attempted to use this code, but I am not getting any output:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

public class practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList stopword = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("stopwords.txt");
            byte b[] = new byte[fis.available()];
            fis.read(b);
            fis.close();
            String data[] = new String(b).trim().split("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                stopword.add(data[i].trim());
            }
            FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("hello.txt");
            byte b1[] = new byte[fis2.available()];
            fis2.read(b);
            fis2.close();
            String data1[] = new String(b1).trim().split("\n");
//                  String myFile="";
            for(int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
                String myFile = "";
                String s2[] = data[i].split("/s");
                for (int j = 0; j < s2.length; j++) {
                    if (!(stopword.contains(s2[j].trim().toLowerCase()))) {
                        myFile = myFile+s2[j]+" ";
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(myFile+"\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File file = new File("hello.txt");
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            int count=0;
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                sc.next();
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Number of words for new file: " + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through your program with the debugger.

Comment: `fis.read(b);` Java may not read the entire file.  You have to check the return code and keep reading if the required amount has not been read.  Also don't try tread binary, for strings use an InputStreamReader to decode the binary.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post sample contents of files _hello.txt_ and _stopwords.txt_ ?

Comment: "_...and have the frequency of the top n elements_" - are you referring the top _n_ elements that were removed or the frequency of words present in the saved file?

Comment: What is the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file *hello.txt* containing `remove leave remove leave remove leave re move remov e leave remove hello remove world!`

And a file *stopWords.txt* containing `remove world`

Using the `Files` class, I can read the entire contents of the file and save it into a (normalized) string. Then, I can use `replaceAll()` from String class to replace a *stopWord* from the file. My example doesn't save the new String back to the file, but this can be easily done by adding the following lines:

```
byte[] strToBytes = helloTxt.getBytes();
Files.write(Paths.get("hello.txt"), strToBytes);
```

The code to read the file and replace all found stop words:

```
public class RemoveWords {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            // per @markspace's comment
            String helloTxt = Files.readString(Paths.get("hello.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
            String stopWordsTxt = Files.readString(Paths.get("stopwords.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
            
            String[] stopWords = stopWordsTxt.split("\\s");
            
            for (String stopWord : stopWords) {
                helloTxt = helloTxt.replaceAll(stopWord, "");
            }
            
            System.out.println(helloTxt);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
 leave  leave  leave re move remov e leave  hello  !
```

To calculate the frequency of words, you may want to check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67051607/2851311) I came up with for another use case.

Comment: Rather than `readAllBytes` I think `readString` is a better choice.  `String(byte[])` is deprecated. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: @markspace edited the answer per your comment. Thanks. However, I am using Java 17 and I don't see `String(byte[])` constructor marked as deprecated.

Comment: Constructor `String(byte[])` is not deprecated (a few overloaded of constructors receiving a byte array were deprecated more than 20 years ago, so it's not a recent change), however, generating an array of bytes and then copying these bytes into the underlying array of a `String` introduces a redundant step. `Files.readString()` is a good choice here.

Comment: That's a good answer. As a word of advice, I think a couple of words about NIO.2 can be useful for OP, since they're using legacy I/O API. Both APIs contain lots of classes, and any beginners tend to confuse `File` and `Files` classes, so one introductory sentence and a link for further reading can be helpful for the questioner and readers.